# Choice between hardware for Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

So I have a choice of following Hardware for deploying cassandra, can anyone help me in deciding in choosing the right one for best performance.

1)First Choice:

```
4 Servers
4 x 2.5GHZ Intel Xeon Processors
4 x 256GB RAM
10Gig/s Network Connectivity
4 x 5TB SSD Drives
```

2)Second Choice:

```
15x 2.0GHZ Intel Xeon
15 x 16GB RAM
10Gb/s Network connectivity
15 x 1TB SSD Drives
```

can anyone please let me know which hardware should I choose for getting maximum IOPS(throughput) with minimum latency ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second choice of course

1) The more machines you have, the better it is because the data is spread on all of them and you'll benefit from parallel processing

2) CPU for the second choice is almost as powerful as the first choice

3) 16Gb of RAM is OK if you have SSD. Usually the bottleneck is the disk I/O